# Excel to DATATABLE using isn't working after hosting

Tags: asp.net, epplus

```
var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage();

pck.Load(File.OpenRead("~\\EXCELS\\Book2.xlsx"));
```

How to map excel after hosting ...

- I tried this code it is not working for me.
- I tried system path it works but after hosting doesn't work
  it shows

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\~\EXCELS\Book2.xlsx'.

Can anyone help me please..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Error: Could not find part of the path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611151/c-sharp-error-could-not-find-part-of-the-path)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the path relative to the website using `Server.MapPath`.

```
pck.Load(File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(@"~\EXCELS\Book2.xlsx")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ~ to get it to work, and change the path a little.